# Animate RenderTransformOrigin

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I would like to modify `RenderTransformOrigin`in a xaml `storyboard`. The value must not be animated, a immediately change would be also fine.
The following code dosn't work:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardFadeIn">
  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin).(Point.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="UserControl" To="0"/>
  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin).(Point.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="UserControl" To="0"/>
</Storyboard>
```

Is it possible to change this property in an animation (using only xaml)?

Errorcode:

```
The property "X" is not a DependencyProperty. To be used in markup, non-attached properties must be exposed on the target type with an accessible instance property "X".
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can Animate the `X` and `Y` of a point structure using `DoubleAnimation`, but you should be able to animate the `RenderTransformOrigin` using a `PointAnimation`

Example:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardFadeIn">
    <PointAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin)" Storyboard.TargetName="UserControl" To="0,0"/>
</Storyboard>
```